# In custom module - No such file or directory in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 5008 of /mnt/www/html/xyzexample/docroot/includes/common.inc)

Tags: 7, javascript

I am newbie and working on Drupal-7.

I have created **custom block module** called '**mycampaign**' to add script to **Retargeting Tags** into each page.

***Script:***

```
<script async src="http://i.simpli.fi/dpx.js?cid=0&segment=Segment+Name&campaign_id=0"></script>
```

But, I am getting this **error:**

**Warning:** file_get_contents(\sites\all\modules\mycampaign\mycampaign.js\mycampaign.js) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 5008 of /mnt/www/html/xyzexample/docroot/includes/common.inc).

Appreciate your help!

.info file for my custom module

```
name = mycampaign
description = This module provides a custom block with dynamic content. 
package = MyModules 
core = 7.x 
; NEW LINE
configure = admin/config/content/mycampaign
scripts[] = mycampaign.js
```

**File code from my custom module:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 *
 * Displays help and module information.
 *
 * @param path 
 *   Which path of the site we're using to display help
 * @param arg 
 *   Array that holds the current path as returned from arg() function
 */
  /**
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/

function mycampaign_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#mycampaign":
      return '<p>' . t("Displays links to nodes created on this date") . '</p>';
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Declaring the block
 */
function mycampaign_block_info() {
  $blocks['mycampaign'] = array(
    // The name that will appear in the block list.
    'info' => t('mycampaign'),
    // Default setting.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $blocks;
} 


function mycampaign_block_view($delta = ' ') {
  if ($delta == 'mycampaign_delta') {
    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('mycampaign block title'),
      'content' => array(
        '#markup' => '<p>' . t('mycampaign block output.') . '</p>',
        '#attached' => array(
          'js' => array('\sites\all\modules\mycampaign\mycampaign.js'),
        ),
      ),
      drupal_add_html_head($viewport, 'viewport')
    );
    return $block;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mycampaign_menu() {
 // $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/content/mycampaign'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Campaign',
    'description' => 'Configuration for My Campaign module',
//    'page callback' => '_mycampaign_page',
    'page arguments' => array('mycampaign_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access mycampaign content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, //Will appear in Navigation menu.
      );
    return $items;

}

function mycampaign_init(){
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('mycampaign', 'mycampaign').'\sites\all\modules\mycampaign\mycampaign.js\mycampaign.js'); 
} 

/**
 * Creating the configuration form
 */

 function mycampaign_contents() {
  //Get today's date.
  $today = getdate();
  //Calculate midnight a week ago.
  $start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0,$today['mon'],($today['mday'] - 7), $today['year']);
  //Get all posts from one week ago to the present.
  $end_time = time();

 //NEW LINE 
 $max_num = variable_get('mycampaign_max', 3);

  //Use Database API to retrieve my campaign.
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created'))
    ->condition('status', 1) //Published.
    ->condition('created', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN')
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC') //Most recent first.
    ->range(0, $max_num) //NEW LINE
    ->execute();
  return $query;
}
/**
 * Validating the data
 */
 /**
 * Implements validation from the Form API.
 * 
 * @param $form
 *   A structured array containing the elements and properties of the form.
 * @param $form_state
 *   An array that stores information about the form's current state 
 *   during processing.
 */
function mycampaign_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $max_num = $form_state['values']['mycampaign_max'];
  if (!is_numeric($max_num)){
    form_set_error('mycampaign_max', t('You must enter a number for the maximum number of posts to display.'));
  }
  elseif ($max_num <= 0){
    form_set_error('mycampaign_max', t('Maximum number of posts to display must be positive.'));
  }
}

/**
 * Specifying a custom permission for a new page
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */

function mycampaign_permission() {
  return array(
    'access mycampaign content' => array(
      'title' => t('Access content for the mycampaign module'),
    )
  );
}


/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
/*
function mycampaign_menu() {
    $items = array();    
    $items['mycampaign'] = array(
        'title' => 'My Campaign',
        'page callback' => '_mycampaign_page',
        'access arguments' => array('access mycampaign content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, //Will appear in Navigation menu.
      );
    return $items;
}
 * */
```

And script in JS file

```
<script async src="http://i.simpli.fi/dpx.js?cid=0&segment=Segment+Name&campaign_id=0"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your .info file and the code from your .module file that is supposed to add the script.

Comment: can you manually load the file by entering it in the browser as a url?

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that Drupal is unable to locate `mycampaign.js`.

This may be because you've got the path wrong, or because the file and/or the directory it is in is so well protected that your web server don't have access to it.

In your case, you have the path wrong on two counts.  Change:

```
function mycampaign_init(){
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('mycampaign', 'mycampaign').'\sites\all\modules\mycampaign\mycampaign.js\mycampaign.js'); 
}
```

into:

```
function mycampaign_init(){
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mycampaign').'\sites\all\modules\mycampaign\mycampaign.js'); 
}
```

Pay attention to the first parameter as well as the path.

You also have two implementations of `hook_menu`.  That should have produced another runtime error.

Since the script is not found, it is not loaded.  I.e. at this point, it doesn't matter what it contains.

Comment: Thanks Free Radical & RoloDMonkey. I have edited the question with code files-

I just noticed wrong path "\mycampaign.js\mycampaign.js'. It is actually just on '\mycampaign.js'
I have changed the corrected path but I am still getting this and won't be able to see my [script] in page source.

Warning: file_get_contents(/sites/all/modules/mycampaign/mycampaign.js) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 5008 of /mnt/www/html/xyzexample/docroot/includes/common.inc).

Comment: Yes, I have cleared all cache.

Comment: try using `$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mycampaign');' to get the path to the module directory.